# String Splitting and Truncating using Regular Expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr, strsplit, tidyverse

I am looking for help implementing a function in R to truncate a `level_stream` string vector of my dataframe in R and haven't had much luck yet. Essentially when a row in the `pre_quiz_score` column is not `NA`, I want to truncate the beginning part of the string up until (and including) the first `|` character, and I want to truncate everything past the last `|` character if a `post_quiz_score` is not `NA` for that row.

```
df <- data.frame(ls = c('123 L0=38/42|425 L0=40/42', NA, '482 L7=7/12|789 L8=5/6|523 L9=2/6'), 
                 pre_quiz_score = c(88, NA, 12), 
                 post_quiz_score = c(NA, NA, 90))
```

I want to implement this in a "tidyverse" way and vectorized to get something like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 ls                  | pre_quiz_score | post_quiz_score   |
| 425 L0=40/42                        | 88             | NA                |
| NA                                  | NA             | NA                |
| 789 L8=5/6                          | 12             | 90                |
```

So far, I haven't gotten `stringr::str_split`, `gsub`, or `sub` to work correctly, mostly because I end up removing just the `|`'s or all the string but the last `|` and after.

I hope that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement the logic as you stated it:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ls = c('123 L0=38/42|425 L0=40/42', NA, '482 L7=7/12|789 L8=5/6|523 L9=2/6'),
                 pre_quiz_score = c(88, NA, 12),
                 post_quiz_score = c(NA, NA, 90),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


df %>%
  mutate(ls=ifelse(!is.na(pre_quiz_score),
                   stri_replace_first_regex(ls, "^[[:alnum:][:blank:]=/]+\\|", ""), ls),
         ls=ifelse(!is.na(post_quiz_score),
                   stri_replace_last_regex(ls, "\\|[[:alnum:][:blank:]=/]+$", ""), ls))
##             ls pre_quiz_score post_quiz_score
## 1 425 L0=40/42             88              NA
## 2         <NA>             NA              NA
## 3   789 L8=5/6             12              90
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to implement! Thanks for introducing me to these useful stringi functions. I'm not an expert on regular expressions, so I'll read about yours, but this worked. =)

Comment: Cool. Ticking the answer button wld help others know this was accurate.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
df$ls <- sub("^[^|]+\\|([^|]+).*", "\\1", df$ls)
df
#            ls pre_quiz_score post_quiz_score
#1 425 L0=40/42             88              NA
#2         <NA>             NA              NA
#3   789 L8=5/6             12              90
```

### Explanation

We match one or more characters that are not a `|` (`[^|]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by a `|` (escape it -`\\|` as a it is a metacharacter), then capture one or more characters that are not a `|` as a group (i.e. inside the parentheses `([^|]+)`) followed by characters until the end of the string (`.*`) and replace it with the backreference of the captured group (`\\1` - as there is only a single capture group and it is the first one, we denote it by 1)

Comment: or `gsub("\\|([^|]+)|.", "\\1", df$ls)` but it might require more explanation :}

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ls = sapply(strsplit(df$ls, "\\|"), function(x) x[2]))

#            ls pre_quiz_score post_quiz_score
#1 425 L0=40/42             88              NA
#2         <NA>             NA              NA
#3   789 L8=5/6             12              90
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer - the first `ls` should start `425`

Comment: @thelatemail i had to extract the `x[2]` instead of `x[1]`

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::separate()` allows you to split up a column into sub-columns. With the `extra = "drop"` argument it will keep only up to `length(into)` columns.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, ls, c("remove", "keep"), sep="\\|", extra = "drop")

#>         remove         keep pre_quiz_score post_quiz_score
#> 1 123 L0=38/42 425 L0=40/42             88              NA
#> 2         <NA>         <NA>             NA              NA
#> 3  482 L7=7/12   789 L8=5/6             12              90
```

I've kept the remaining part after the first `|` but you can remove that too if you don't need it.

Comment: I've been using `tidyr::separate` to do some future parsing on this "level stream" data, but this isn't quite the output I needed, and some of these `ls` strings are 2k+ character strings. Once I trim up the first and last 'parts' of `ls` then I use `tidyr::separate` with its default arguments to start converting data types and parse the timestamps appropriately.